# Multiple electoric signatures using Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-office-2003, digital-signature

Searching for an answer whether Office Word 2003 files can support multiple electronic signatures each resource that i came up with mentions that it can be done on Word 2007+...

Here are but a few resources @ Technet:

1. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/word/thread/30f2bbc8-d24f-4f3b-930d-fe2d69bacb55
   *"From your description, It seems impossible to add multiple Electronic signature to the same document.
   Office 2007/2010 can let you add multiple digital signatures to the same document.
   For 2007
   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc545901(office.12).aspx
   For 2010
   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc545900.aspx"*
2. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc545900.aspx
   *"Office 2013 applications let you add multiple digital signatures to the same document."*

Can it be accomplished using Word 2003?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This cannot be done with Office 2003.

Comment: My official source is the lack of a support article for Office 2003 and the fact Office 2003 isn't supported by Microsoft.